# How to implement tree structure type form filling dynamically in js

Tags: javascript, treeview

I want to create a dynamic tree structure, where I want to edit/delete nodes and its data. At each level of this tree structure we have different forms to add/edit/delete data.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Telerik Kendo UI TreeView](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/index). It's free, easy to implement and supports all of your requirements.

Basic example:

```
<div class="demo-section k-header">
    <ul id="treeview">
        <li data-expanded="true">
            <span class="k-sprite folder"></span>
            My Web Site
            <ul>
                <li data-expanded="true">
                    <span class="k-sprite folder"></span>images
                    <ul>
                        <li><span class="k-sprite image"></span>logo.png</li>
                        <li><span class="k-sprite image"></span>body-back.png</li>
                        <li><span class="k-sprite image"></span>my-photo.jpg</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li data-expanded="true">
                    <span class="k-sprite folder"></span>resources
                    <ul>
                        <li data-expanded="true">
                            <span class="k-sprite folder"></span>pdf
                            <ul>
                                <li><span class="k-sprite pdf"></span>brochure.pdf</li>
                                <li><span class="k-sprite pdf"></span>prices.pdf</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><span class="k-sprite folder"></span>zip</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><span class="k-sprite html"></span>about.html</li>
                <li><span class="k-sprite html"></span>contacts.html</li>
                <li><span class="k-sprite html"></span>index.html</li>
                <li><span class="k-sprite html"></span>portfolio.html</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#treeview").kendoTreeView();
    });
</script>
```